# MSBuild and csproj: how to conditioning c# file inclusion/compiling

Tags: c#, android, msbuild

I have a **Xamarin** Android+iOS application with a .NET standard library, and I want to condition the compiling of some **.cs** files in my library depending on the **package** in the AndroidManifest.xml / the **bundle identifier** in the info.plist. This because I need to customize the app for more customers with different configurations.
The condition should also consider if my configuration is Debug or Release (file need to be excluded only in **Release** configuration).

```
<Compile Include="ConditionalFile.cs" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
```

The condition for the debug, I need to add some kind of "or clause" and to fill it, maybe with a bash script launched when it's time to compile the apk/ipa.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I've found is this one:

- Custom property with the id of my app: `<PackageId>it.mpic.x</PackageId>`
- bash script which changes the `<PackageId>` element with the right app-id before the release
- Compile condition in or: `Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' Or '$(PackageId)' == 'it.mpic.x1'"`